# Customize Barcode Scanner screen

Tags: meteor

I am using this package:

cordova:com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner

and you scan using this function:

```
  Template.barcode_scanner.events({
    'click button': function () {

    cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
  function (result) {
    if(!result.cancelled)
    {
      alert("Barcode type is: " + result.format);
      alert("Decoded text is: " + result.text);
    }
    else
    {
      alert("You have cancelled scan");
    }
  },
  function (error) {
      alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
  }
);

    }

  });
```

I am wondering how I can customize the scanning screen. I need to add a few buttons to the scanning screen. Anyone know how?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by using the package:

cordova:cordova-plugin-qrscanner

Docs:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-qrscanner

It is fully customizable, but only reads QR codes.